# Simple Injector with Domain Events

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I'm trying to implement Domain Events into my system, but I'm stuck. I am using SimpleInjector, and I think i'm missing something.

Domain Event:

```
public static class DomainEvent
{
    public static IEventDispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }

    public static void Raise<T>(T @event) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(@event);
    }

}
```

SimpleInjectorEventDispatcher

```
public class SimpleInjectorEventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly Container container;
    public SimpleInjectorEventDispatcher(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent eventToDispatch) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IDomainHandler<>).MakeGenericType(eventToDispatch.GetType());
        var handlers = this.container.GetAllInstances(handlerType);

        foreach (dynamic handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.HandleEvent((dynamic)eventToDispatch);
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleInjector

```
container.Register<IEventDispatcher, SimpleInjectorEventDispatcher>();
```

The IEventDispatcher Dispatcher is always null. How do I make sure it is correctly initialised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The IEventDispatcher Dispatcher is always null.

Simple Injector will not magically initialize any static members of some random class for you. As long as you didn’t' set this static field yourself at start-up, nobody will.

I would however urge you to stop using this static `DomainEvent` class **completely**. This design is rooted in an [old article](http://udidahan.com/2008/08/25/domain-events-take-2/) from Udi Dahan, but he himself abandoned the idea of using static classes for this purpose a long time ago. He is currently advising against it, as am I.

Static classes are troublesome from the perspective of testability and discoverability. From that perspective, the use of Dependency Injection is a much better alternative.

The solution to your problem is therefore really straightforward: Remove the static `DomainEvents` class from your code base and inject the `IEventDispatcher` into the constructors of consumers that require publishing events.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I will take your advice and ditch the static class. Does that mean that all my entities will require a constructor accepting an IEventDispatcher?

Comment: Entities? No. Entities should not get their dependencies using Constructor Injection. If you wish to apply DDD, you should use Method Injection, i.e. the entity method that actually uses the dependency should require it through its method.

Comment: Thanks again! Another related question: The SimpleInjectorEventDispatcher has a Container field. How can I set that field to use the container from my SimpleInjectorConfiguration?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. You already supply it as constructor argument. Simple Injector will automatically inject itself.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know that. I'll try it right now and get back to you. Thanks for your time, and your answer!

Comment: And you can also do: `container.RegisterSingleton<IEventDispatcher>(new SimpleInjectorEventDispatcher(container));`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136339/discussion-between-wekslie-and-steven).